# Create a dictionary using a foor-loop and add a label for each in python

Tags: python

I have the following data, however I want to create a dictionary using a foor loop.

```
data = [("TEXT 1", 'no'), ("TEXT 2", 'yes'), ("TEXT 3", 'no'), ("TEXT 4", 'no'), ("TEXT 5", 'yes')]
```

Is it possible to do that?

I need a dictionary with this structure:

```
[({"TEXT 1": 'no'}, "Comment 1"),
 ({"TEXT 2": 'yes'}, "Comment 2")]
```

Comment 1, Comment 2 and so on are arbitrary labels that I am assigning and are not mentioned in my dataset.

Comment: Does "Comment 1" come from the input?

Comment: Your result isn't a dictionary. It's a list of tuples containing a dictionary in each tuple.

Comment: @Aaron No, it doesn't. It  is arbitrary label that I am assigning

Comment: Where does it come from when you're creating the result?

Comment: If you have a tuple `t = (x, y)` you can turn it into a dictionary with `{t[0]: t[1]}`. Use that inside a list comprehension that processes `data`.

Comment: You can use `enumerate(data)` to get indexes when processing `data`, and then put the index into the labels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to write this down:

```
data = [
    ("TEXT 1", 'no'), ("TEXT 2", 'yes'), ("TEXT 3", 'no'),
    ("TEXT 4", 'no'), ("TEXT 5", 'yes')
    ]


# Expected Output:
# [({"TEXT 1": 'no'}, "Comment 1"),
#  ({"TEXT 2": 'yes'}, "Comment 2")]


def newdata(data_arg):
    print([
        ({tup[0]: tup[1]}, f'Comment {tup[0].split()[1]}') for tup in data_arg
        ])


newdata(data)
```

This will get the expected output for all tuples in the dictionary, "print" can be switched to return if needed.

Another approach:

```
def func(oldstring):
    ANS = []
    cmt = 0
    for i in oldstring:
        new_dic = {}
        cmt += 1
        new_dic[i[0]] = i[1]
        ANS.append((new_dic, 'comment' + str(cmt)))
    return ANS


print(func(data))
```

These may solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn the tuples into dicts and for the comments you can use `enumerate` to get the numbering:

```
output = [(dict(t), f'Comment {i}') for i, t in enumerate(data)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this method will help.

```
data = [("TEXT 1", 'no'), ("TEXT 2", 'yes'), ("TEXT 3", 'no'), ("TEXT 4", 'no') ("TEXT 5", 'yes')]
result = []
for k,v in data:
    r = f"comment {k[5]}"
    dat={}
    dat[k]=v
    tup = (dat,r)
    result.append(tup)
```